# Self referencing loop detected when serializing objects in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using MVC 5 Web API with Entity Framework 6 database first while i'm serializing my Object to JSON i faced a problems with Self referencing loops, i googled to identify the problem and i found many solutions so i'm wondering what is the best model ever?

I Found:

1. use [JsonIgnore] but i will need to add it every time i update the model form DB
2. Remove virtual from the collection
3. create new layer of Data Transfer Objects (DTO)
4. Use JsonSerializerSettings (Doesn't work with me since it generates "$id", "$ref")

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know that the answer is "It depends" right? However in my experience I have come to the conclusion that more often than not we end up with DTO layer. It is useful for solving a myriad of problems of this kind while other solutions solve only this particular instance. In other occasions we had to flatten the object (Employee.CompanyName instead of Employee.Company.Name) and other similar issues. The downside is that you cannot directly expose IQueryable from your API although we did something to translate expression trees. So basically I guess it is a question of whether you care about the IQueryable exposed directly from the service.